# TFS 2010: Create a new Trunk From Branch (while keeping the old)

Tags: tfs, branch

We currently have the following structure in one of our projects.

- Trunk (Version 1)

  - Version 2

    - Version 3

Version 1 has become legacy
Version 2 is something which never got released and isn't needed anymore. But Version 3 is a branch from it.
Version 3 is the future and should be the new trunk.

So what I want to do is the following:

Make Version 3 the new trunk but without loosing anything from the current trunk.

So I stumbled upon "Reparenting with no parent" and from what I read it seems to do what I need, but I couldn't find anything about what would happen to the current trunk. Will there be two trunks?

Or would it be better to create a new tfs project from Version 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reparenting is when you want to move a branches parent from an old branch to a new branch for example.  You want to create a new trunk to branch off of.

In general I would suggest to add a label of "Version 1" to the current trunk as a way to go back to the current version in the future if necessary.  This is how you will "keep" the current trunk.  Then you will probably need a baseless merge from version 3 to trunk.  Then trunk is the latest and you can start branching new versions again.

Here is a [good post](http://roadtoalm.com/2012/09/19/reparent-of-a-source-controlled-branch-why-and-how/) with more details.

Comment: thanks, I did exactly what you suggested (I kinda feared baseless merges, that's why I didn't even consider them).
But it worked as expected and without problems.